# SymGetModuleInfo64 returns empty GUID

Tags: c++, windows, guid, symbols, callstack

I am trying to obtain the module GUIDs from the current process by enumerating the loaded modules using **EnumerateLoadedModules64** and in the enumeration callback load modules using **SymLoadModuleEx** and after that getting module information using **SymGetModuleInfoW64**.

For all modules with an existing PDB this call succeeds and the **PdbSig70** contains the GUID for the module. However, if I delete the PDB file, the call succeeds but the *GUID is empty*.

I know that the information is in the exe file since *dumpbin.exe /headers [exefile]* can display the GUID information without the PDB file.

The question is how to obtain this information from the running process. I want this information to be able to have users producing crash reports without a PDB with callstack addresses and module information so that I can look up the symbols using a symbol server at a later time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was trying to do the same thing and found this:

```
struct CV_INFO_PDB70
{
    DWORD  CvSignature;
    GUID Signature;
    DWORD Age;
    BYTE PdbFileName[];
};

ULONG dirEntrySize;
BOOLEAN mappedAsImage = TRUE;
size_t imageAddress = static_cast<size_t>(IMAGEHLP_MODULEW64_VAR.BaseOfImage);
IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY* debugDirectory = reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY*>(sImageDirectoryEntryToDataEx(reinterpret_cast<PVOID>(imageAddress), mappedAsImage, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DEBUG, &dirEntrySize, NULL));    size_t debugEnd = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(debugDirectory) + dirEntrySize;
while(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(debugDirectory) < debugEnd)
{
    if(debugDirectory->Type == IMAGE_DEBUG_TYPE_CODEVIEW)
    {
        break;
    }
    ++debugDirectory;
}
CV_INFO_PDB70* information = reinterpret_cast<CV_INFO_PDB70*>(static_cast<DWORD>(imageAddress) + debugDirectory->AddressOfRawData);
```

There's more information here:
http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/debuginfomatch.html

Comment: Ooh, shiny! I will have a look at this to see if it solves my problem! Thanks in advance!